# Difference between loop and with_items behavior with a single item and a list of items

Tags: ansible

While looking at a question here, came across another question.

Let's assume a variable with list of dicts like so:

```yaml
some_var:
  - k: key1
    m: value1
  - k: key2
    m: value2
  - k: key3
    m: value3
```

Looping over `some_var` using below code gives each item as expected.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ some_var | flatten(1) }}"
```

However, when placing the loop variable as a list like below, it doesn't loop through individual dict item rather prints the whole list.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: 
    - "{{ some_var | flatten(1) }}"
```

What is the reason for this difference in `loop` behavior compare to `with_items` that works as expected in both scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in behaviour your are observing between `with_items` and `loop` is actually due to the way `with_items` flatten the list for you, implicitly, which makes it happen later than when you flatten it explicitly in your `loop`, as advised by the Ansible documentation.

So, here the difference just stands in the moment where the list is flattened:

- Using `with_items`, the list is flattened internally by Ansible, so it would be an equivalent to:

  ```yaml
  [ some_var ] | flatten(1)
  ```
- When, in the `loop` documentation of Ansible, as you saw it, you have to flatten the list yourself, but by introducing a list one level upper, your flatten happen too early, and, thus, is an equivalent to:

  ```yaml
  [ some_var | flatten(1) ]
  ```

So if you are looking to exactly and explicitly reproduce the same behaviour as `with_items` in your loop, you have to do this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ [ some_var | flatten(1) ] | flatten(1) }}"
      vars:
        some_var:
          - k: key1
            m: value1
          - k: key2
            m: value2
          - k: key3
            m: value3
```

Which works, as expected:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'k': 'key1', 'm': 'value1'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "k": "key1",
        "m": "value1"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'k': 'key2', 'm': 'value2'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "k": "key2",
        "m": "value2"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'k': 'key3', 'm': 'value3'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "k": "key3",
        "m": "value3"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

This is because you are creating a list of list in the second example, while the loop only loops over the first level of a list.

So your first, working playbook is an equivalent to looping on the variable debugged here under:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ some_var | flatten(1) }}"
      vars:
        some_var:
          - k: key1
            m: value1
          - k: key2
            m: value2
          - k: key3
            m: value3
```

That gives:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "k": "key1",
            "m": "value1"
        },
        {
            "k": "key2",
            "m": "value2"
        },
        {
            "k": "key3",
            "m": "value3"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Your second example, though, is an equivalent to:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 
          - "{{ some_var | flatten(1) }}"
        ## Note that this above syntax is actually an equivalent to:
        # msg: "{{ [ some_var | flatten(1) ] }}"
      vars:
        some_var:
          - k: key1
            m: value1
          - k: key2
            m: value2
          - k: key3
            m: value3
```

That gives:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "k": "key1",
                "m": "value1"
            },
            {
                "k": "key2",
                "m": "value2"
            },
            {
                "k": "key3",
                "m": "value3"
            }
        ]
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

See how you have a list of list in this second example?

---

So, the first element of the first example is

```yaml
{'k': 'key1', 'm': 'value1'}
```

As you expect it, while the first element of the second one, is just a list containing all of your element:

```yaml
[   
    {
        "k": "key1",
        "m": "value1"
    },
    {
        "k": "key2",
        "m": "value2"
    },
    {
        "k": "key3",
        "m": "value3"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε, +1 for the details. I actually noticed this part of the details while working on this question. Sorry that I missed vital wordings from the question in relation with with_items which could have made the question more precise. Basically, I am unclear on the difference how with_items work but not loop for the second scenario. Corrected the wordings of the question too.

Comment: @Moon this is because of the way the flatten is happening internally and implicitly in `with_items` module, when, in loops you have to explicitly flatten. See the beginning of the edited answer.

Comment: Perfect! That explains.